# Need to show that $e^{ikx}, -N \le k \le N$ is a basis of dimension $2N+1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have some troubles understanding how to prove the following statement

> Show that $(e^{ikx})_{\mid k \mid \leq N} $ is a basis of dimension
> $2N+1$.

I feel like each one of these vectors lives in the complex plane, which is of dimension $2$, and therefore I don't understand how $2N+1$ vectors could be linearly independent.

**Edit**

The proposition I need to show is the following: $T_n$, the set of trigonometric polynomials of degree $n$, is a vector space of dimension $2n+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question does not make sense unless you specify the space in which you are working.

Comment: A basis of what vector space? Without this information the question makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your help! The misunderstanding of the problem clearly led to my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

If they had been vectors living in the complex plane (which, mind you, is often enough a 1-dimensional vector space), then they would be complex numbers. They aren't complex numbers, though, they are complex *functions*.

And the (standard) vector space of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ (or $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, perhaps) is infinite dimensional, regardless of whether the base field is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.

As others have pointed out in the comments, however, there is a lot of compulsory information missing from the problem statement. I have guessed, based on experience, what they mean, but technically it's not a well-posed problem. The following would be better:

> Given an $N\in \Bbb N$, show that the set of functions $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ given by $f_n(x)=e^{ikx}$ for $-N\leq  
> n\leq N$, with standard function addition and scaling form a basis for a vector space over $\Bbb R$ (or over $\Bbb C$) of dimension $2n+1$.

Comment: This is exactly the proposition I need to prove, sorry for the missing informations.

Comment: @Pale Well, now, hopefully, You understand the problem better.

Comment: I clearly do, thanks for your fast reply.